# 400 Bad Request!! when I try to send ajax request to Servlet in spring mvc

Tags: java, ajax, spring, servlets

```
/*ajax request to servlet to perform update operation*/
var savedata={
              video_Title:videotitle, 
              video_duration:videoduration,
              video_Url:videourl,
              video_Description:videodescription

    };
         $.ajax({
           url:'videoUpdate',  
           type:'POST',  
           cache:false,
           data: savedata,
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           success: function(response) {
              alert("Updated Successfully");
        },
        error:function()
        {
        alert("oops sorry something went wrong. we apologize for the inconvenience");
        }   
        });



/*Controller Class*/

@RequestMapping(value ="videoUpdate",method =  RequestMethod.POST,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody Status updateVideo(@RequestBody Video video) {

        try {

            System.out.println("update  servlet");
            dataServices.updateVideo(video);
            return new Status(1,"video updated Successfully");
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
        return new Status(0,e.getMessage().toString());
        }
}
```

My question is how to receive ajax-json request data in my servlet class.Is this is the correct way to catch a set of data from ajax in spring mvc.Or other annotation is required for avoiding 400 error!?

Comment: Log your errors, you'll get actual information on what's going wrong.

Comment: @codeseeker As you use `@RequestBody Video video` , are the data you are sending binds with model class ? seems more of request data mis-match ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `400 Bad Request` seldom happens because the `url` viz `videoUpdate` could not be mapped to appropriate mapping.

This could be because you might not be passing the arguments required to make to point cut.
I would suggest you to inspect following portion of your code:

```
var savedata={
              video_Title:videotitle, 
              video_duration:videoduration,
              video_Url:videourl,
              video_Description:videodescription

    };
```

And make sure you are passing required parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

that means you are expecting JSON data in return - if it's not valid JSON then it goes to the error block.

You are probably returning a string :

```
return new Status(0,e.getMessage().toString());
```

Try omitting the `contentType` line. Also posting browser console errors might help us determine the problem easier.

Note: If you want to specify the outgoing data type there's a `dataType` setting.

Comment: thanks for the advice @Dropout.The problem is fields of the Video class not exactly match the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the URL you are hitting is correct, you could look at whether the fields of the Video class exactly match the JSON you are POSTing